# How to "dockerize" Flask application?

Tags: python-2.7, docker, flask, dockerfile

I have Flask application named as rest.py and I have dockerize but it is not running.

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
tasks = [
          {
            'id': 1,
            'title': u'Buy groceries',
            'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
            'done': False
          }
        ]

@app.route('/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Dockerfile is as follows

```
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
COPY . /rest
WORKDIR /rest
RUN pip install -r Req.txt 
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["rest.py"]
```

I have build it using this command...

```
$ docker build -t flask-sample-one:latest
```

...and when I run container...

```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-sample-one
```

returning the following output: 
    7d1ccd4a4471284127a5f4579427dd106df499e15b868f39fa0ebce84c494a42
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `-d` is detach (it's running in the background -- is that your intention for testing it?)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to reinforce your concepts about **Docker**, in order to understand how it works, and then you will achieve your objectives regarding "dockerizing" whatever application.

Here is an [article](http://re-source-tech.blogspot.com/2017/03/docker-getting-started.html) which can give your some first steps.

An official [HOWTO](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) will also help you.

Some observations that might help you:

- check if your Req.txt contains `flask` for installation
- before `dockerizing`, check if your application is working
- check your running containers with `docker ps` and see if your container is running
- if it is running, test your application: `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/tasks`
  *

**One more thing:**

- your JSON has an **OBJECT** with an **ARRAY** with just one **ELEMENT**

> Is that what you want for your prototype?

Take a look on this [doc](http://www.json.org/), about the **JSON** standard.

Comment: Thats OK I have just started learning docker. Could you tell me what have I done wrong?

Comment: Take a look on my answer, @sky , and have a read on both links. Also, take a loot on my observations. You just need to reinforce some concepts :).

Comment: My container is not running and it stop after giving this output- 13cf014998af516a1e11f4130e226632b996d9355a439a452a22d6c42b7a074b

Comment: I believe that you should take a look if your Flask application is working, before creating a new docker image. Your have to go little by little, eliminating problems, "divide and rule".

Comment: @sky I think you also need

`RUN pip install -y flask`

in your docker file. See the output of the container itself with `docker logs [container-id]` to figure out what's going on inside.

Comment: He needs to verify if `flask` is listed inside his Req.txt, as I have aleady mentioned. It it is not, there is no possibility to have anything running.

Comment: Req.txt alone doesn't do anything if you don't run some python setup if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thats what I have mention in Req.txt, It is installing flask from there only.

Comment: @sky, have you tried to run your application, BEFORE creating a docker image + creating a container?

Comment: Yes I have run my application and it is giving output properly.

Comment: Check the article which I have mentioned on my question. It'll help you to create your docker container, using the network stack from your Host Machine, eliminating the need of port declarations and other possible problems, and also, review the `COPY` and `WORKDIR` statements from your Dockerfile.

Comment: OK I will try that too.

Answer (score 0):

1. The output you get is the container ID. Check with `docker ps` whether it keeps running.
2. Use `docker logs [container-id]` to figure out what's going on inside.
3. Some problems I can find in your question:

   1. Change the `app.run` line to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)`. From the point of view of the container, its services need to be externally available. So they need to run on the loopback interface, like you would run it if you'd set up a publicly available server on a host directly.
   2. Make sure that Flask gets installed. Your docker image file requires all the commands to make it work from a blank Ubuntu installation.
   3. *Please do not forget* to deactivate debug if you'd ever expose this service on your host. Debug mode in Flask makes it possible for visitors to run arbitrary code if they can trigger an exception (it's a feature, not a bug).

After that (and building the container again [1]), try `curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/tasks` on the host. Let me know if it works, if not there are other problems in your setup.

[1] You can improve the prototyping workflow with Flask's built-in reloader (which is enabled by default) if you use a volume mount in your docker container for the directory that contains your python files - this would allow you to change your script on the host, reload in the browser and directly see the result.

Comment: Can I use it on RESTclient directly for get instead of curl?

Comment: Sure, test it with whatever you like. I think people generally like to use `curl` as a first step because it's the fastest way to see whether the routing does what you want.

Comment: When I run container it is giving output as 13cf014998af516a1e11f4130e226632b996d9355a439a452a22d6c42b7a‌​074b and then it stops. I have added host='0.0.0.0 and also set debug mode to False